# How to change the axes' origin and direction?

Tags: plotting

I have manipulated an image and want to `ListPlot` it. However, the result is not to my liking because the conventions for drawing images and plots are different. Images have the origin at the top left and increase in Y downwards while plots have the origin at the bottom left and increase in Y upwards.

What is the easiest way to reconcile the difference, preferably without manipulating the data?

Comment: What do you mean by list plotting an image?

Comment: You start with an image, process it, and end up with an array which you display with `ListPlot`.

Comment: Do you mean `ListPlot` or something like `ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot`. If you are refering to `ArrayPlot`/`MatrixPlot` then yes, they are different, the origin is in the bottom left vs. top left. You might try making your data an image again `Image@data`...

Comment: As a good ol' neuroscientist, I wish that `DataReversed` could be applied to `ListPlot` and friends (we flip the y-axis on EEG signals- tradition!!!). I've used the `{#, -#2} & @@@ ` solution in the past, the `Line[args___]` seems cool, but I sure wish this was just 'fixed' so `DataReversed->True` would just 'work'. Sigh.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

#### 1: Reversing the image in a 2D plot (`ArrayPlot` or `MatrixPlot`)

Simply use `DataReversed -> True`. This has the effect of flipping the image along the horizontal axis. For example:

```
func[x_, y_] := Sinc[y ^2 + x^3];
data = Table[func[x,y], {x, -π, π, 0.1}, {y, -π, π, 0.1}];
ArrayPlot[data, DataReversed -> #] & /@ {True, False} // GraphicsRow
```

[image]

#### 2: Changing the origin in a 1D plot (`ListPlot` or `Plot`)

Use `AxesOrigin -> {x, y}` to change the origin to where ever you like. For example:

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 2 Pi}, AxesOrigin -> {0.5, 0.5}]
```

[image]

#### 3: Changing the direction of the y-axis (or x-axis) in a 1D plot

Flipping the y-axis in a 1D plot is a bit more involved and is a very common approach in displaying depth plots. You can implement this in Mathematica by negating your input to `ListPlot` and assigning custom ticks with a function. Here's an example:

```
x = Sin /@ Range[0, 2 π, 0.1];
ListPlot[-x, Ticks -> {Automatic, Function[{xmin, xmax}, 
    Table[{i, -i, {0.02, 0}}, {i, N@FindDivisions[{xmin, xmax}, 10]}]]}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 12):

I wrote some code for this a few years ago. Haven't looked at it in a long time but it may be useful. [It is in the Wolfram library archive](http://library.wolfram.com/infocenter/MathSource/7525/ReverseListPlot.nb?file_id=7064) (that seems to have been all but abandoned by both users and Wolfram).

[image]

Answer (score 6):

In the docs check the entry [`ImageData>Options>DataReversed`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bdpj8f2q-csu948) and the first example in the section [`Properties & Relations`](http://wolfram.com/xid/0bdpj8f2q-gh5xx) to see if it helps with what you need.

Comment: I wish it did but I could not feed it to `ListPlot`. It says `ArrayPlot` et al only. Close...

Comment: @Emre, a simple example showing how you go from an image to `ListPlot` would help everyone - what is the data in your `ListPlot` and how does it relate to the image?

Comment: It's a 2D integer array. It can be from binarizing or segmenting the image. I want select all the pixels belonging to a particular cluster, using `Position[filtered_image,n]`, which gives me a list of pixels, and run `ListPlot`.

Answer (score 4):

It's really not clear from your question what you want, but here is one simple interpretation:

```
dat = Table[{x, x^2 Exp[-x^2]}, {x, -5, 5, 0.1}];

ListLinePlot[dat, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ticks = Table[{-x, x}, {x, 0, 0.4, 0.05}];

ListLinePlot[{#, -#2} & @@@ dat, PlotRange -> All, Ticks -> {All, ticks}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This could be automated, but since I don't know if this is what you want I'm leaving it there for now.

Comment: Purely graphical solution without touching data: `ListLinePlot[dat, PlotRange -> All] /. 
 Line[args___] :> Scale[Line[args], {1, -1}]`. `PlotRange` goes nuts though (Probably a bug).

Comment: @Yu-SungChang  `ListLinePlot` is turning `PlotRange -> All` into explicit lower and upper bounds, which I don't consider to be a bug.  Sometimes it's helpful, and sometimes it's not.

Comment: I actually ended up going with `Apply[{#1, -#2}]`, as suggested here, but there were several useful answers and comments so I wanted to thank everyone.