# How to reverse the direction of the y axes

Tags: plotting, syntax, options

I have a similar question to [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/how-to-change-the-axes-origin-and-direction/3751#3751). Unfortunately, the answers there didn't help me. I would like to plot a simple function with the normal `Plot` function. However, I want the origin of my plot to be in the upper left corner, the x-axes to grow to the right and the y-axes to grow down. How can I do this?

Comment: I would call it a duplicate of [flipping axis on plot](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5714/5478) but the trick with `ScallingFunctions` is no longer working with `ListPlot`, at least on V9.0.1.0 WinXP/Win7.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

<strike>A little bit tricky because it is not supposed to work:</strike> `ScallingFunctions` are documented since V11 but this works for V10 and maybe erlier versions.

```
Plot[x^2, {x, 0, 3}, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}, 
                     PlotRange -> {{0, 4}, {-10, 0}}, 
                     AxesStyle -> {Arrowheads@.05, Arrowheads[{-.05, 0}]}]
```

[image]

[How can one find undocumented options](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/809/5478)

Comment: How to do the same with Graphics?

Comment: I wanted to suggest to post a separate question but it seems you've done this already.

Answer (score 4):

Not pretty, but using supported capabilities.

```
x = #^2 &@Range[0, 10, .001];

ListPlot[-x, DataRange -> {0, 10}, PlotStyle -> PointSize[.002], 
 InterpolationOrder -> 2, PlotRange -> {{0, 10}, {0, -100}}, 
 AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, 
 Ticks -> {Automatic, 
   Function[{mn, mx}, 
    Table[{i, -i, {0.02, 0}}, {i, N@FindDivisions[{mn, mx}, 10]}]]}]
```

[image]