# Set plot axes to be positive in both directions

Tags: plotting

How can I set the axes of a plot to be positive in both directions, along the lines of this image? [image]

I've looked through some questions on how to change the axis direction ([here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/how-to-change-the-axes-origin-and-direction), [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41025/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-the-y-axes) and [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/45261/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-the-y-axes-on-graphics)) but they obviously don't fully answer my problem, and I've not got further than the options given in those questions. Presumably the answer lies in the `Ticks` function, but I'm not sure how to implement it.

**Edit**

I am aware of custom labels and tick positions from the documentation, but am curious about a more automatic way to do it. I was thinking along the lines of the accepted answer to [How to change the axes' origin and direction?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/how-to-change-the-axes-origin-and-direction?answertab=votes#tab-top), where this is given as a way of reversing the axis direction.

```
x = Sin /@ Range[0, 2 π, 0.1];
ListPlot[-x, Ticks -> {Automatic, Function[{xmin, xmax}, 
    Table[{i, -i, {0.02, 0}}, {i, N@FindDivisions[{xmin, xmax}, 10]}]]}]
```

Is there a similar method I could use based on `xmin`, `xmax` and `N@FindDivisions[]`, or is custom labels the way forward?

Comment: Have you seen the `Ticks` option?

Comment: I have, perhaps to clarify, how would I use the ticks option to do this?

Comment: @blochwave Did you read [the documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Ticks.html) on it?  You need to specify tick positions with custom labels.  See the docs on how, last example under Scope -> Tick positions and labeling.

Comment: I did, I was wondering if there was a way to do it based on `xmin`, `xmax` and `N@FindDivisions`? As in #3 of the accepted answer here: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/how-to-change-the-axes-origin-and-direction?answertab=votes#tab-top - I've updated my question to clarify this, sorry that it wasn't clear.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do what you are asking for.

```
tickSpec[i_Integer] /; Mod[i, 10] == 0 := {i, Abs[i]}
tickSpec[i_Integer] := {i, ""}
With[{nTicks = 13}, 
  ticks[xmin_, xmax_] := Table[tickSpec @ i, {i, FindDivisions[{xmin, xmax}, nTicks]}]]

Plot[{}, {x, -30, 30},
  PlotRange -> {Full, {-30, 30}},
  AspectRatio -> Automatic,
  Frame -> True,
  Axes -> False,
  FrameTicks -> {{ticks, None}, {ticks, None}}]
```

[image: plot]

Comment: That's wonderful, thank you!