# Switching direction of y-axis

Tags: plotting, version-8

I'm trying to reverse the direction of the y-axis on a parametric plot, with a frame. I'm using ParametricPlot because it was an easy way to switch the x-axis with the y-axis. I have seen many variations of this question, but none seem to be all that straightforward for ParametricPlot + frame. Is there a simple, elegant way to do this on Mathematica? Perhaps a function like ScalingFunctions which works for ParametricPlot (ex. [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/41025/how-to-reverse-the-direction-of-the-y-axes))?

Here is some example code:

```
ParametricPlot[{x^4, x}, {x, 0, 5}, PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic}, 
Axes -> False, ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
FrameLabel -> {{Style["x", FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Times", 
 FontColor -> Black], None}, {Style["Some function", 
 FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Times", FontColor -> Black], 
Style["Some Title", FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Times", 
 FontColor -> Black]}}, RotateLabel -> False, 
PlotStyle -> {Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2]}, 
FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15], AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

Comment: `ScalingFunctions` seems to work for me, using version 10.3.1:  http://i.stack.imgur.com/F8YyV.png

Comment: Interesting, I'm using version 8.0.4.0 and it doesn't work for me. Is it a newer feature or something?

Comment: It's so new it isn't even documented, which is why it shows up in red.  I don't have version 8 installed here, so I can't really come up with a workaround at the moment

Comment: No worries, thank you for the info!

Comment: You may need to manually adjust the `Tick` marks yourself, look at some of the solutions here:  http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/5714/flipping-axis-on-a-plot

Comment: I just tried a few of those, the solution by Peter Breitfeld works fine if I remove the frame. But, errors prevent it from working with a frame.

Comment: The method using data tables works fine without frames as well, but my plots are actually ranging from 0 to 60000 (or more), with more complex functions, so run time increased significantly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are willing to do a fair amount of work you can edit your original plot by manually altering the `y` values and tick marks for the y-axis.

Here is your plot

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{x^4, x}, {x, 0, 5}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic}, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {
    {Style["x", FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      FontColor -> Black], None},
    {Style["Some function", FontSize -> 14, 
      FontFamily -> "Times", FontColor -> Black], 
     Style["Some Title", FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      FontColor -> Black]}
  },
  RotateLabel -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> {{Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2]},
                {Green, AbsoluteThickness[2]}}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15],
  AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

The strategy will be to make our own tick marks for the y-axis and to manually change the `y` values embedded in the line that is drawn with `5-y`. Use `ReplaceAll` in order to accomplish the changes.

To reduce the verbiage create the tick marks outside of the replacement command. Ticks can have the form: `{{y1, label1, {plen1, mlen1}}, ...}`.

```
yticks = Map[If[Mod[#, 1] == 0,
               {#, ToString[5 - #], {0.007, 0}},
               {#, "", {0.003, 0}}] &,
              Range[-1/5, 5 + 1/5, 1/5]
            ];
```

Now try the following replacement

```
plot /. Line[data_] :> Line[({First[#], 5 - Last[#]} & ) /@ data] /.
  (FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}) ->
   FrameTicks -> {{yticks, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}
```

resulting in

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Edits/Solution (given by Jack LaVigne on chat)**:
If I instead want the range for x to be 0 to 60000, with tick labels every 10000 and ticks every 2000, one way to achieve this is as follows (for Mathematica 8.0.4.0):

```
yticks = Map[If[Mod[#, 10000] == 0,
               {#, ToString[60000 - #], {0.007, 0}},
               {#, "", {0.003, 0}}] &,
              Range[-2000, 60000 + 2000, 2000]
            ];
```

Then:

```
plot = ParametricPlot[{x^4, x}, {x, 0, 60000}, 
  PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic}, Axes -> False, 
  ImageSize -> 500, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {
    {Style["x", FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      FontColor -> Black], None},
    {Style["Some function", FontSize -> 14, 
      FontFamily -> "Times", FontColor -> Black], 
     Style["Some Title", FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Times", 
      FontColor -> Black]}
  },
  RotateLabel -> False, 
  PlotStyle -> {Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2]}, 
  FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15],FrameTicks -> {{yticks, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}},
  AspectRatio -> 0.6]
```

Followed by:

```
plot /. Line[data_] :> Line[({First[#], 60000 - Last[#]} & ) /@ data] /.
  (FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}) ->
   FrameTicks -> {{yticks, Automatic}, {Automatic, Automatic}}
```

If you are using a newer version of Mathematica, simply using the old solution (not in this new order, with the addition of FrameTicks to the original plot command) with the updated numbers (ex. 60000,2000,etc.) will do the trick too. Thanks again!

Comment: Okay, thank you, I'll give that a try!

Comment: Go to chat [here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/42987/reverse-y-direction?tab=general)

Answer (score 1):

**This works in V8.0.4,** but the behavior has changed since then.  (It gives an error in V10.4.1, for instance.)

```
ParametricPlot[{x^4, x}, {x, 0, 5}, 
 PlotRange -> {Automatic, Automatic}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {{Style["x", FontSize -> 15, FontFamily -> "Times", 
     FontColor -> Black], 
    None}, {Style["Some function", FontSize -> 15, 
     FontFamily -> "Times", FontColor -> Black], 
    Style["Some Title", FontSize -> 20, FontFamily -> "Times", 
     FontColor -> Black]}}, RotateLabel -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {Blue, AbsoluteThickness[2]}, 
 FrameTicksStyle -> Directive[FontSize -> 15], AspectRatio -> 0.6,
 ScalingFunctions -> {Automatic, {-# &, -# &}},               (* ScalingFunctions, plus *)
 FrameTicks ->                                                (* FrameTicks *)
   {{Charting`ScaledTicks[{-# &, -# &}], Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{-# &, -# &}]},
    {Automatic, Automatic}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Okay thank you, looks like an elegant solution!

Comment: @Canada709 You're welcome!