# Density plot for eigenvalues of a matrix

Tags: plotting, list-manipulation, graphics

I am trying to make a density plot of $|min~[Im(v)]|$ (where $v$ are the eigenvalues of a matrix) as function of $\gamma$ (horizontal axis) and $T$(vertical),  The code upto now is

```
    ListDensityPlot[
 Table[Min[
   Im /@ Eigenvalues[
     With[{k = 2, p = Pi/2}, 
      With[{a = -2 Cos[p], b = -2 Cos[p] - \[Gamma]/(1 + Abs[T]^2)^2, 
        c = (\[Gamma]*T^2*E^(2 I*p))/(1 + Abs[T]^2)^2, n = 2*k + 1}, 
       mat = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 
           Join[ConstantArray[a, n - (k + 1)], {b}, 
            ConstantArray[a, n - (k + 1)]], 
          Band[{2, 1}] -> ConstantArray[1, 2 k], 
          Band[{1, 2}] -> ConstantArray[1, 2 k], 
          Band[{n + 1, n + 1}] -> 
           Join[ConstantArray[-a, n - (k + 1)], {-b}, 
            ConstantArray[-a, n - (k + 1)]], 
          Band[{n + 1, n + 2}] -> ConstantArray[-1, 2 k], 
          Band[{n + 2, n + 1}] -> 
           ConstantArray[-1, 2 k], {n + k + 1, k + 1} -> -c, {k + 1, 
            n + k + 1} -> c}, {2 n, 2 n}];
       mat]]]], {\[Gamma], -30, 30, 0.1}, {T, 0., 5, 0.1}], 
 PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {{-30, 30}, {0, 5}}]
```

which gave me [image]

However, my required output should be close to the following
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

The required output is for `k=49` case, however it takes longer to get an output with $198\times 198$ matrix ($k=49$), so I thought one could get atleast something similar for a smaller matrix. Therefore I used $k=2$ just to see if I get any close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems to me like you've already gotten the correct result, just rotated a bit. I've switched $T$ and $\gamma$ in your code.

```
    ListDensityPlot[
 Table[Min[
   Im /@ Eigenvalues[
     With[{k = 2, p = Pi/2}, 
      With[{a = -2 Cos[p], b = -2 Cos[p] - \[Gamma]/(1 + Abs[T]^2)^2, 
        c = (\[Gamma]*T^2*E^(2 I*p))/(1 + Abs[T]^2)^2, n = 2*k + 1}, 
       mat = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 
           Join[ConstantArray[a, n - (k + 1)], {b}, 
            ConstantArray[a, n - (k + 1)]], 
          Band[{2, 1}] -> ConstantArray[1, 2 k], 
          Band[{1, 2}] -> ConstantArray[1, 2 k], 
          Band[{n + 1, n + 1}] -> 
           Join[ConstantArray[-a, n - (k + 1)], {-b}, 
            ConstantArray[-a, n - (k + 1)]], 
          Band[{n + 1, n + 2}] -> ConstantArray[-1, 2 k], 
          Band[{n + 2, n + 1}] -> 
           ConstantArray[-1, 2 k], {n + k + 1, k + 1} -> -c, {k + 1, 
            n + k + 1} -> c}, {2 n, 2 n}];
       mat]]]], {T, 0, 5, 0.1}, {\[Gamma], -30, 30, 0.1}], 
 PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {{-30, 30}, {0, 5}}]
```

[[image: Reverse <span class=]$\gamma$ and $T$ ">](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FyQre.png)

Also, the `Y-axis` in your bottom picture is reversed. You can use `ScalingFunctions` for that.

```
    ListDensityPlot[
 Table[Min[
   Im /@ Eigenvalues[
     With[{k = 2, p = Pi/2}, 
      With[{a = -2 Cos[p], b = -2 Cos[p] - \[Gamma]/(1 + Abs[T]^2)^2, 
        c = (\[Gamma]*T^2*E^(2 I*p))/(1 + Abs[T]^2)^2, n = 2*k + 1}, 
       mat = SparseArray[{Band[{1, 1}] -> 
           Join[ConstantArray[a, n - (k + 1)], {b}, 
            ConstantArray[a, n - (k + 1)]], 
          Band[{2, 1}] -> ConstantArray[1, 2 k], 
          Band[{1, 2}] -> ConstantArray[1, 2 k], 
          Band[{n + 1, n + 1}] -> 
           Join[ConstantArray[-a, n - (k + 1)], {-b}, 
            ConstantArray[-a, n - (k + 1)]], 
          Band[{n + 1, n + 2}] -> ConstantArray[-1, 2 k], 
          Band[{n + 2, n + 1}] -> 
           ConstantArray[-1, 2 k], {n + k + 1, k + 1} -> -c, {k + 1, 
            n + k + 1} -> c}, {2 n, 2 n}];
       mat]]]], {T, 0, 5, 0.1}, {\[Gamma], -30, 30, 0.1}], 
 PlotRange -> All, DataRange -> {{-30, 30}, {0, 5}}, ScalingFunctions -> {Identity, "Reverse"}]
```

[image: Reversed Y-axis]

When using `Reverse` in `ScalingFunctions`, you have to adjust the ticks also. I wasn't able to figure that out yet, [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/41026/13515) might help.

You can change the colors by adding a `ColorFunction`. For example, adding `ColorFunction -> "TemperatureMap"`. Though to get colors like in your picture, you'd have to write a specific function.

[image: ColorFunction TemperatureMap]

*Note: This was done in Mathematica 11.0, earlier versions may not support `ScalingFunctions` on `ListDensityPlot`.*

Comment: Thanks. So you mean that my x-axis was $T$, instead of $\gamma$? What is on the x-axis and y axis in your answer now? Secondly, the scale in the required figure appears to be different>? on the y-axis..? One more thing, is it possible to sharpen the colors a bit?

Comment: @AtoZ Yes, $T$ and $\gamma$ were switched around. I made an edit to the answer.

Comment: Thanks. So in yourlast update, $\gamma$ is on x-axis and $T$ on y-axis?

Comment: @AtoZ Indeed, $\gamma \in [-30, 30]$ on ``x-axis`` and $T \in [0, 5]$ on ``y-axis``, just as you defined.