# How can I reverse the direction of the y axis of a list vector plot?

Tags: plotting

I want to reverse the direction of y-axis of my plot. What should I incorporate in my code? I am attaching part of my code where the plotting action is occurring.

```
streamData = 
   Table[{datax[[i, n - j + 1]], datay[[i, n - j + 1]]}, {i, 1, m}, {j, 1, n}];

ListVectorPlot[streamData, 
  StreamPoints -> 250, 
  Axes -> True, 
  Frame -> False, 
  VectorPoints -> All, 
  VectorColorFunction -> "Rainbow"]
```

Comment: Welcome! Your code is missing the definition of `datax` - please add that so anyone interested can reproduce your example. Take a look at https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/41025/131, which may already help you.

Comment: I am importing some experimentally generated data files in datax. If you want to reproduce, then you will need my data files also. Your can generate any data as per your own choice and verify.

Comment: It is usually very helpful (and considered good style) to provide working code. If you want to maximize your chances of getting answers, you should make doing that as easy as possible. Your specific data set might pose it´s own special challenge, too. Without working code, your question may also be closed for being incomplete.

Comment: The title of the question is inconsistent with the body of the question. Are you trying to reverse both axes or just the y-axis? You should edit the question to clarify rather than just comment.