# Revert y-axis in RegionPlot

Tags: plotting

I have the following code:

```
Module[{n = 300, p = 0.29}, 
  RegionPlot[{y > (1/2)*(n - x) && y + x <= n && y > p/(1 - p)*x}, 
    {x, 0, n}, {y, n, 0}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
    PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]]}]]
```

which will give you the yellow region on the LHS in the figure below.

[image]

**Question**: I want to revert the y-axis of the RegionPlot so that the axis will look like the RHS in the figure above and the position and the shape of the region change accordingly. This would be the first step to make a ternary RegionPlot.

Comment: See, e.g., [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/how-to-change-the-axes-origin-and-direction/3751#3751) and related/linked posts, and do a search for "reverse axis"...

Comment: @rasher, I saw that post too. However, `DataReversed` is not even a keyword in `RegionPlot`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**1.** If you need to change just the tick labels you can use `FrameTicks` as follows:

```
rp1 = Module[{n = 300, p = 0.29}, 
   RegionPlot[{y > (1/2)*(n - x) && y + x <= n && y > p/(1 - p)*x}, {x, 0, n}, {y, n, 0},
    FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]]}, 
    FrameTicks -> {{{#, ToString[300 - #]} & /@ Range[0, 300, 50], None}, {All, None}}]]
```

[image]

**2.** If you need to change the region polygon too, you can simply change all `y`s to `(n-y)` in the first argument of `RegionPlot`:

```
 rp2 = Module[{n = 300, p = 0.29}, 
    RegionPlot[{(n - y) > (1/2)*(n - x) && (n - y) + x <= n && (n - y) >
      p/(1 - p)*x}, {x, 0, n}, {y, n, 0}, FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"}, 
   PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]]}, 
   FrameTicks -> {{{#, ToString[300 - #]} & /@ Range[0, 300, 50], None}, {All, None}}]]
```

[image]

**3.** Post-processing the graphics primitives using `GeometricTransformation[_,AffineTransform[_]]` and the options using `ReplaceAll`:

```
rp = Module[{n = 300, p = 0.29},
RegionPlot[{y > (1/2)*(n - x) && y + x <= n && y > p/(1 - p)*x}, {x, 0, n}, {y, n, 0},
    FrameLabel -> {"x", "y"},  PlotStyle -> {Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.5]]},
    ImageSize -> 350]];
rpb = MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, AffineTransform[{{{1, 0},{0, -1}},{0, 300}}]] &,
            rp, {1}];
ticks = MapAt[# /.{a_, b_Real, {c_, 0.}, d___} :>{a, Round[300. - b, 1], {c, 0.}, d} &, 
        AbsoluteOptions[rpb, FrameTicks], {{1, 2, 2}}];
Row[{rp, rpb, 
 Show[rpb, ticks, ImagePadding-> {{Automatic, Automatic}, {Automatic, 0}}]},Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

**4.**   ... use [this function](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/11355/125) to get the final output:

[image]