# How to make a 2D plot of 3 variables (sample picture attached)

Tags: plotting, graphics, graphics3d

Is it possible to plot that kind of graph in *Mathematica*? (picture attached)
[image: Would be nice to have something like this]

If yes, it can be used to visualise a simple "balance system" of the form:
`X = f[e]`; `x = g[r]`; `X = -x`.

Usually we have two separate plots, but it would be nice to combine them as shown above.
Let's deal with linear functions for simplicity. 
With some abuse of conventions:

```
X[ϵ_] := 1 - 0.5 ϵ    
x[r_] := -0.5 + 0.5 r
```

Then:

```
plotX = Plot[X[ϵ], {ϵ, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 3}, ImagePadding -> 25]    
plotx = Plot[x[r], {r, -1, 1}, PlotRange -> {-1, 3}, ImagePadding -> 25, PlotStyle -> Red]
```

I have found several solutions how to combine them on the site, but they seem to solve "problems" separately. `Overlay` seemed simplest. But that is still far from satisfaction.

```
Overlay[{plotX, plotx}]
```

The tricky (for me) things about the plot are:

1. horizontal axis is common but reverted for a down-looking plot.
2. down-looking axis (r) is supposed to grow down (or reversed ticks, at least).
3. magnitudes of variables `ϵ` and `r` are different,
4. labels as reflected are also required.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Read the [faq]!
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge.
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Comment: Perhaps, there could be 2 alternatives. 1) Play with Axes properties, but I’ve failed to manage them on positive and negative part independently (Reverse directions, switch on / off). 2) Combine 2 graphs with a Grid :[that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6877/do-i-have-to-code-each-case-of-this-grid-full-of-plots-separately/6882#6882) and [that](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/3747/how-to-change-the-axes-origin-and-direction) like), but with the down plot reversed. Any suggestion, @Öskå ?

Comment: @garej I'm sorry I was a bit too hasty indeed, you can't play with left/right (or top/bottom) axes independently indeed.

Comment: Anyway, @Öskå, thank you for your helpful editing and remarks!

Comment: Is it normal that you have no ticks on your plot?

Comment: No, @Öskå, it is not. It would be great, of course, to have Ticks along side with respective Labels (with proper sign and color), but I thought it might complicate the task and did not draw them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a version that takes as a reference a `Plot` of the two functions. It will only work if the *x-range* and the *y-range* are of the same magnitude. If not the placement of the axes labels will be screwed.

```
(* Plot the original function *)
X[ϵ_] := 1 - 0.5 ϵ
x[r_] := -0.5 + 0.5 r
p = Plot[{X[r], x[r]}, {r, -1, 1}];
(* Get the attributes of the plot p *)
pl = Cases[p, Line[x_] :> x, Infinity];
pc = Cases[p, _?ColorQ, Infinity][[;; -2]];
pr = PlotRange /. Quiet@AbsoluteOptions[p, PlotRange];
pat = First@Cases[p, AbsoluteThickness[x_] :> x, Infinity];
axeso = AxesOrigin /. Quiet@AbsoluteOptions[p, AxesOrigin];
axes = Flatten[{Thread@{Array[axeso &, {2}], Thread@{First@pr, axeso}}, 
                Thread@{Array[axeso &, {2}], Thread@{axeso, Last@pr}}}, 1];
(* labels *)
labelxplus = {"-X", "+X"}; labelxminus = {"-(-X)", "+(-X)"};
labelyplus = {"r", "ε"}; labelyminus = {"-r", "-ε"};
labels = {labelxminus, labelyminus, labelxplus, labelyplus};
disp = #[Rescale[#@axeso, #@pr] & /@ {Last, First}, .05] & /@ {Subtract, Plus};
tips = {1 - 0.925, .925};
(* rebuild the plot *)
postlabels = {{#, First@First@disp } & /@ tips, {Last@First@disp , #} & /@ tips, 
              {#, First@Last@disp } & /@ tips, {Last@Last@disp, # } & /@ tips};
Graphics[{
  Thread@{{Red, Blue, Red, Blue}, Arrow /@ axes}, 
  Thread@{pc, AbsoluteThickness@pat, Line /@ pl},
  Text[#1, #2] & @@@ Thread@{Flatten@labels, Scaled /@ Flatten[postlabels, 1]}
  },
 Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Now with `p = Plot[{x, x/2, Sin@x}, {x, -10, 10}];`:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

As mentioned in the beginning, if the axes ranges are not of the same magnitude, the labels might overlap or get out of the frame. For example with `p = Plot[{x, x^2}, {x, -100, 100}];`:

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 3):

```
Xf[ϵ_] := 1 - 0.5 ϵ
xf[r_] := -.5 + 0.5 r;

blueaxis = {Directive[Blue, Thick, Arrowheads[{0, .05}]], Arrow @@ # &};
redaxis = {Directive[Red, Thick, Arrowheads[{-.05, 0}]], Arrow @@ # &};
txtF = Text[Style[#, 20, Italic], #2] &;
axeslabels = txtF @@@ Transpose[{{"ε", "r", "+X", "-X", "-(-X)", 
      "+(-X)"}, {{.1, 2.7}, {-.1, -.7}, {.8, .3}, {-.8, .3}, {.8, -.3}, {-.8, -.3}}}];

ParametricPlot[{{0, 3 ConditionalExpression[x, x >= 0]}, {0,  ConditionalExpression[x, x < 0]}, 
   {ConditionalExpression[x, x >= 0], 0}, { ConditionalExpression[x, x < 0], 0}, 
   {x, Xf[x]}, {x, xf[x]}}, {x, -1, 1}, 
 PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-3, 3}}, Axes -> False, 
 PlotStyle -> {blueaxis, redaxis, blueaxis, redaxis, Orange, Purple}, 
 Epilog -> {axeslabels}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 500]
```

[image]

**Update:** Post-processing an input plot to the add colored axes and axes labels:

```
axesF = With[{pr = PlotRange[#]}, With[{labels = txtF @@@ 
        Transpose[{#2, {{.1, .9 pr[[2, 2]]}, {-.1, .9 pr[[2, 1]]}, 
                  {.8 pr[[1, 2]], .3}, {.8 pr[[1, 1]], .3}, {.8 pr[[1, 2]], -.3}, 
                  {.8 pr[[1, 1]], -.3}}}]},
     FullGraphics@ ParametricPlot[{{0, pr[[2, 2]] ConditionalExpression[x, 0 <= x]},
        {0, Abs@pr[[2, 1]] ConditionalExpression[x, x < 0]},
        {pr[[1, 2]] ConditionalExpression[x, 0 <= x], 0},
        { Abs@pr[[1, 1]] ConditionalExpression[x, x < 0], 0}},
       {x, pr[[1, 1]], pr[[1, 2]]}, PlotRange -> pr, Axes -> False,
       PlotStyle -> {blueaxis, redaxis, blueaxis, redaxis},
       Epilog -> {labels}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio]]] &;


plt1 = Plot[{Xf[x], xf[x]}, {x, -1, 1}, Axes -> False, Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{-1, 1}, {-3, 3}}, AspectRatio -> 1/GoldenRatio, ImageSize -> 500];

Show[plt1, axesF[plt1, {"ε", "r", "+X", "-X", "-(-X)", "+(-X)"}]]
```

[image]